# Why doesn't this execute the function given for RxScala's doOnSubscribe function?

Tags: rx-scala

```
  val x: Observable[Int] = Observable.just(1).doOnSubscribe(() => println(s"subscribed"))
  val y = x.subscribe(t => println(s"got item: $t"))
  println("all done")
```

I would have thought this code would print

```
subscribed
got item: 1
all done
```

But it doesn't print the initial "subscribed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `doOnSubscribe` is:

```
def doOnSubscribe(onSubscribe: => Unit): Observable[T]
```

That is, it takes a *by-name* argument. So you have to use it as follows:

```
Observable.just(1).doOnSubscribe(println(s"subscribed"))
```

*by-name* means that the `println` will not be executed when passed to `doOnSubscribe`, but only once `doOnSubscribe` uses it.

What you were passing to `doOnSubscribe` is a 0-arity function, i.e. an expression of type `() => Unit`, and by discarding the value of an expression, Scala can turn any expression into Unit, so that's why it compiled.

This is IMHO confusing, and I'd prefer a `() => Unit` argument instead of `=> Unit`, then it would work as you expected.

Btw: you are [not the first](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/issues/175) to be puzzled by this ;-)

Comment: Ouch - you're right, I totally missed that.  I added a comment to that bug - I think there's a way you can support both styles, at the cost of requiring an extra import.