# RxScala ConnectableObservable.doOnSubscribe is never called?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-scala

```
val observable = Observable(...)
    .publish
val subscription = observable.connect

observable.doOnsubscribe(() => doSomething)
    .subscribe()
```

The `doSomething` is never called. The exact same code for RxJava was working properly. It seems for whatever reason it was never propagated to the underlying Java Observable

Update:
So my workaround is

```
observable.asJavaObservable
    .doOnSubscribe(new Action0 {
        override def call(): Unit = {
            doSomething
        }
    }}.asScala
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: what versions of rx-scala, scala?

Comment: RxScala 0.26.5 and Scala 2.11

Answer (score 0):

`publish` creates a connected Observable. This is a bit different from a standard Observable and you need to call `connect()` in order for the connected Observable to start emitting. See the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html).

Comment: I did call connect, it's just I omitted here to focus on what matters. What matters is that the exact same code in RxJava or in my workaround works, but not in pure RxScala. Let me just put the connect if that makes it clearer

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your signature. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274683/why-doesnt-this-execute-the-function-given-for-rxscalas-doonsubscribe-function).

Comment: your hint solve the problem. You can post it as answer and I'll mark it as the right answer